# Permission denied (publickey) ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin, ssh-keys

I am attempting to ssh into a a EC2 machine and ssh has stopped working.  I'm not sure how I broke it but it is now unable to connect.  I already tried creating a new key but it is not helping.

```
$ ssh -vT ****@****.****-2.compute.amazonaws.com 
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-****.****-2.compute.amazonaws.com [****] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Brad/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA ****
debug1: Host '****.****-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Brad/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/Brad/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Brad/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Brad/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Brad/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have replaced all of the personal info with *.

Thank you

Comment: This is off-topic for SO as it is about SSH configuration and not _programming_.  It belongs on [su]

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your command you are referring the ssh private key. Try running command as below:

**`ssh -i <path_to_the_private_key> ubuntu@<EC2_Hostname>`**

In above command, note that I have used the username as `ubuntu`. Depending on which AMI you are using, you should change the username which corresponds to that AMI.